# Can you create code for an iPhone 'Add to Home Screen' button to put on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, safari

When you view any webpage on Safari/iphone there is an icon/button at the bottom of the browser which you can click (it's the square with the arrow in it), and then on the drawer that opens up there is a button called 'Add to Home Screen' (IOS7) that basically allows you to add an icon/link to your iphone's home screen which links to the aforementioned webpage.

Does anyone know a way to add a button to an actual webpage that allows people to do the same as the above for people viewing on an iphone? I realise that this would replicate the button that appears in the safari browser, but many non-tech users are unlikely to pay much attention to these safari buttons and so if we created a button with more context then it would allow visitors to more easily add an icon to their home screen for easy access to the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this from a webpage, only via the feature provided by Mobile Safari.

You could add something [like this](https://github.com/cubiq/add-to-homescreen) to the website. It prompts the user and calls out the location of the button to add the page to the home screen.

https://github.com/cubiq/add-to-homescreen